# how to switch between mariadb and mysql

Tags: database, installation, magento2.3.1, mariadb, opensource

my magento2 is reading mariadb server and database is connected to that, I am trying o use mysql instead but I had no luck, it does not recognize the database at all although I have added the following:

```
    'db' => [
    'connection' => [
        'indexer' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'm2',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'model' => 'mysql4',
            'engine' => 'innodb',
            'active' => '1',
            'persistent' => NULL
        ],
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'm2',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'model' => 'mysql4',
            'engine' => 'innodb',
            'active' => '1'
        ]
    ],
    'table_prefix' => ''
```

I also tried using a new user name and password for only mysql to make it understand to read from there but still it is connecting to mariadb instead.

How can I switch it to mysql? my mysql version is 5.7.28 and my magento version is 2.3.1

In Abstract.php line 128:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'm2'

how can I switch so it understands to read from mysql server instead of mariadb?

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Setup\De
claration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder::processReferenceKeys() must be of the type ar
ray, null given, called in C:\wamp64\www\scosche-industries\vendor\magento\frame
work\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder.php on line 127 and defined in C:
\wamp64\www\scosche-industries\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema
\Db\SchemaBuilder.php:137
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp64\www\scosche-industries\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\S
chema\Db\SchemaBuilder.php(127): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\S
chemaBuilder->processReferenceKeys(NULL, Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declarat
ion\Schema\Dto\Schema))
#1 C:\wamp64\www\scosche-industries\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\S
chema\SchemaConfig.php(66): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\Schema
Builder->build(Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema))
#2 C:\wamp64\www\scosche-industries\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\S
chema\UpToDateDe in C:\wamp64\www\scosche-industries\vendor\magento\framework\Se
tup\Declaration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder.php on line 137
```

Comment: which Magento version, you have using?  Open Source version OR  community version

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used wrong  connection for indexer.

```
 'indexer' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'm2',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'model' => 'mysql4',
            'engine' => 'innodb',
            'active' => '1',
            'persistent' => NULL
        ],
```

Magento `open source version` does not have different connection for indexer.It is worked in Commerce version means sperate resource Connection.

**Connection Might be like:**

```
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'm2',
                'username' => 'user',
                'password' => 'xxx',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'resource' => [
        'default_setup' => [
            'connection' => 'default'
        ]
    ]
```

**Also, put proper mysql username and password and the mysql user should have read r/write connection at database.**

Comment: I did not touch it manually thats how it was created while I have installed it , what i did was I installed with a raw database from scratch. an empty database. I have the paid version. does that mean open source version?

Comment: are you saying I remove my indexer array and only keep default?

Comment: You have paid for Magento source code ?  If yes, then it should be commerce version or Cloud version

Comment: yes I have cloud version

Comment: and cloud works with mariadb and now my localhost is doing it but I wanna do mysql

Comment: it did not have model and engine when i installed it, I added them myself but didnt really help it

Comment: use magento  answer at your local

Comment: have you  clear cache  properly?

Comment: the thing is i cannot clear cache it gives me errors of unknown database

Comment: please take a look I updated the question on one more error that i get

Comment: You have to clear cache properly if you have a copied cache folder.  Also changes database  name to m2 another without numeric  at name and see what  happen

Comment: I changed it to some none existant database and it says the same error

Comment: i will look later. Now busy

Comment: Is the issue resolve?

Comment: No its not im now trying to import db in maria db but its so ridiculous